# Azure Powershell - get-AzureVM returning an accountName does not exist error?

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm at a bit of a loss with where to start with this one.

I have one Azure account with 2 subscriptions (I'm not the full admin just a co-admin so can't edit them) and both are called Pay-As-You-Go with different IDs.

I can connect powershell to the account and log in, list the subscriptions, select the subscription that I want to use.

However when I issue the get-AzureVM command either in a script or from the 
command line I get the error below:

```
Get-AzureVM : Account with name 'Pay-As-You-Go' does not exist.
Parameter name: accountName
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureVM
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureVM], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.ServiceManagement.IaaS.GetAzureVMCommand
```

I can enter a specific VM name and service name and get the same error back.

My confusion stems from the fact that I haven't specified that account name as far as I'm aware in the command.

I have been playing around on the machine quite a lot this morning with writing wrapper scripts to allow selection of different user name connections via a prompt and selection of the relevant subscription but nothing I'm aware would have affected this command.

I can still run the commands below and get the output I expect:

```
Get-AzureAccount

Get-AzureSubscription -current
```

So the session is working for sure.

The VM I am trying to query was created from a custom image this morning and I can RDP to it and it seems to be running normally

Any ideas would be great?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do that it is to Execute the command Clear-AzureProfile it will require you to login again the problem it is that you account has been logged out. The sam problem happens when you have 2 different subscription for 2 different accounts and you change from one to another after executing some commands on the first one. Using the clear command after the switch solves that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure of the root cause of this one, restarting the machine, opening closing the IDE etc had no effect.

But I did find by running Remove-AzureAccount and then running Add-AzureAccount again that it resolved.

So I just removed my account from powershell and re-added it to solve...